# Can a lambda have "C" linkage?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

The title more or less says it all.  I've got the following bit
of code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct xloper12;

class Something
{
public:
    std::string asString() const;
};
extern std::vector<Something> ourSomethings;

class ExcelOutputLoader
{
public:
    void load( std::vector<std::string> const& value );
    xloper12* asXloper() const;
};

extern xloper12* ProcessException( std::string const& functionName );

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) xloper12*
getSomethingList()
{
    try {
        std::vector<std::string> results;
        results.reserve( ourSomethings.size() );
        std::transform(
            ourSomethings.begin(),
            ourSomethings.end(),
            std::back_inserter(results),
            []( Something const& o ) { return o.asString(); } );
        ExcelOutputLoader out;
        out.load( results );
        return out.asXloper();
    } catch (...) {
        return ProcessException( "GetSomthing" );
    }
}
```

I've replaced most of the non-standard headers with dummy
declarations; the issue is in the last function (which is
designed to be called from Excel).  Basically, when compiled
with Visual Studios 2012, I get the following warning:

```
falseWarning.cc(34) : warning C4190: '<Unknown>' has C-linkage specified, but re
turns UDT 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' which is incompatible with C

        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
        ]
```

(repeated four times, for good measure).  But as I understand
it, lambda defines a class with an `operator()` member, and not
a function.  And (§7.5/4) "A C language linkage is ignored in
determining the language linkage of the names of class members
and the function type of class member functions."  Which would
mean that the `extern "C"` should be ignored on the lambda.

It's not a big thing: it's only a warning, and it's easy to work
around (have the `extern "C"` function call a C++ function which
does the actual work).  But I would still like to know: is there
something fundamental that I've not understood about lambda, or
is it the people developing Visual C++ who don't understand it.
(In the latter case, I'm worried.  Since portability isn't an
issue, we've started using lambda intensively.  But if the
author's of the compiler don't understand it, then I'm worried.)

EDIT:

Some more tests.  If I write something like:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void
funct1()
{
    extern std::string another();
}
```

I also get the warning.  This time, I would say it was correct.
`another` *is* a function in namespace scope, and it is declared
inside an `extern "C"` block, so it should have "C" linkage.
(Interestingly enough, I also get a warning to the effect that
I might have been bitten by the most vexing parse problem.  The
`extern` should have been enough for the compiler to realize
that I wasn't trying to define a local variable.)

On the other hand, if I write something like:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void
funct2()
{
    class Whatever
    {
    public:
        std::string asString() { return std::string(); }
    };
    std::string x = Whatever().asString();
}
```

There is no warning.  In this case, the compiler does correctly
ignore the specified "C" linkage on a member function.

Which makes me wonder a little bit.  Is the compiler treating
the lambda as a class with an `operator()` function (as it
should), or is it treating it as a function?  It looks like that
latter, and that makes me worry if there aren't other subtle
problems involved, probably only visible when there is capture
(and probably only in very special cases then).

Comment: Looks like compiler bug to me. It's `getSomethingList` that's `extern "C"`, and it doesn't return a string. Its linkage specification should be irrelevant to its internal implementation details.

Comment: I agree with the opinion that this might be a VS bug. Has you tried on VS2013?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes and no.  If I explicitly declared a function in the `extern "C"`, or a pointer to a function, I would expect them to also be `extern "C"`.

Comment: Another comment is that Herb Sutter is on the C++ standard committee so I wouldn't worry about microsoft not understanding the standard.

Comment: I don't have access to VS2013.  I was hoping someone here might be able to answer that (and also what it does with other compilers---g++ 4.7.2 seems to be happy with it, but I'm not sure that that means anything; g++ seems to ignore `extern "C"`, at least with regards to the type system.).

Comment: @Pedrom I don't think that Herb is actually involved in writing the compiler.  And strictly speaking, Microsoft doesn't understand anything; it's the individuals who work for the company who understand (or not).

Comment: The express version should be enough (http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40787). I can try it for you but after work because I use a linux machine at the office.

Comment: FWIW, the multiple repetitions of the warning are most likely because VC generates overloads of a lambda's `op()` for all the different calling conventions. It's probably generating a warning while trying to match each

Comment: I'd say that `extern "C" ...;` is read by VC++ as if `extern "C" { ...; }` so everything inside is declared with C linkage. Both interpretations are equivalent except for the possibility of local functions... or lambdas.

Comment: @rodrigo I hope so.  There should be no difference between `extern "C" { void f() {} }` and `extern "C" void f() {}`, regardless of what is in the function.  The only real issue is the sentence I quote: if lambda defines a class, with an `operator()` member function, then the member function should not have "C" linkage.  At least if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be underspecified by the standard.

5.1.2:

> 3 - [...] The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*. [...]
>   5 - The closure type for a *lambda-expression* has a public inline function call operator [...]
>   6 - The closure type for a *lambda-expression* with no *lambda-capture* has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator.

7.5:

> 4 - [...] In a *linkage-specification*, the specified language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage declared within the *linkage-specification*. [...] A C language linkage is ignored in determining the language linkage of the names of class members and the function type of class member functions. [...]

So neither the function call operator or the conversion function to function pointer have C language linkage as they are class member functions; but since 5.1.2p6 does not specify *where* the function returned by the conversion function is declared, its type may have C language linkage.

On one hand, if we consider an example in 7.5p4:

```
extern "C" {
  class X {
  // ...
  void mf2(void(*)()); // the name of the function mf2 has C++ language
                       // linkage; the parameter has type pointer to
                       // C function
  };
}
```

This suggests that a conversion to function pointer would have return type pointer to C function, as long as the C function type is declared inline of the conversion declaration or otherwise within the extern "C" block:

```
extern "C" {
  class Y {
    (*operator void())(); // return type pointer to C function
  };
}
```

On the other hand, the function is required to have *the same effect* as the function call operator, which is not possible if C language linkage prevents it; we *could* conclude that the function must be declared outside the extern "C" block and similarly the return type of the conversion function.  But this may impose extra workload on the compiler writers.

Comment: The key, it seems, is the point 6 of 5.1.2.  I wasn't aware of this, but it clearly explains the issue (and I would expect the generated free functions to have C binding).  More importantly: it indicates that the standard does require lambdas without capture to behave differently, and the behavior of the Microsoft compiler is not due to some misunderstanding of the standard.  I'm reassured.

Answer (score 3):

The 4 errors is what clued me in.

Stateless lambdas have an implicit conversion to functions.  In MSVC, there are something like 4 calling conventions supported.

So your lambda creates 4 function signatures *within* the `extern "C"` block, one per calling convention.  These function signatures pick up the `extern "C"` and become illegal, as they return `std::string`.

A possible fix might be to split the body from the interface.  Either one step (`extern "C"` the prototype, then implement), or have your `extern "C"` function call a non-`extern` `inline` function that has the lambda.

Another approach would be to create a dummy variable and capture it.

It isn't the `operator()` that is generating the error, it is the signature-matching pure function pointers implied by a pure stateless lambda.

Comment: As ectamur points out, the extra free functions are actually required by the standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, the existence of *one* of them is required: MSVC provides conversions to multiple different calling conventions (which is rather nice and solves some callback headaches when talking to MS APIs), which is why you get the error 4 times over.